# Having trouble converting if into cond

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to understand why these two functions are giving me different results. Is there some case that I am missing when I converted the nested if statements into conds? The functions are supposed to count elements in a list recursively.

```
(define (countall x L)
    (if (null? L) 0
        (if (pair? L) (+ (countall x (car L)) (countall x (cdr L)))
            (if (eq? x L) 1 0)
        )
    )
)
(countall 'a '(a (a))) ;gives 2

(define (countall x L)
    (cond
        ((null? L) 0)
        ((pair? L) (+ (countall x (car L)) (countall x (cdr L))))
        (else (eq? x L) 1 0)
    )
)
(countall 'a '(a (a))) ;gives 0?
```

I've tried stepping through by hand, but I'm having a hard time finding what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` case contains three different expressions: `(eq? x L)`, `1` and `0`. This is treated like a `begin` block (one might say that each case of a `cond` automatically starts a `begin` block), meaning that all three expressions are evaluated in order and then the value of the last expression is returned. So your `else` case always returns `0` regardless of whether `x` equals `L` or not.

`(eq? x L)` shouldn't be an expression in the `else` block, it should be one of the conditions of your `cond`. So it should be:

```
(cond
    ((null? L) 0)
    ((pair? L) (+ (countall x (car L)) (countall x (cdr L))))
    ((eq? x L) 1)
    (else 0))
```